# HOW TO MAKE create var array dynamic in C#

Tags: c#, ajax

In my controller I'm using following code to return the 2 lists to ajax request:

```
public JsonResult getdata(int seat_plane_id)
{
    int lid;
    layoutsController L = new layoutsController();
    JsonResult result = L.getlayouts(seat_plane_id);
    List<layouts> L1 = (List<layouts>)result.Data;
    List<SeatPlans>[] allUser = new List<SeatPlans>[2];
    for(int i=0; i<L1.Count; i++)   
    {
        String lid1 = L1[i].ticket_no_start;
        lid = Int32.Parse(lid1);
        allUser[i]= new List<SeatPlans>();
        allUser[i]= db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList();
    }

    var v = new { allUser0 = allUser[0], allUser1 = allUser[1] ,allUser2= allUser[2] };
    return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm catching the returned value in ajax request as:

```
success: function (v) {
       loadData(v.allUser0);
       loadData(v.allUser0);
    }
```

But my problem is: I will have a dynamic size of `allUser` (size is `L1.Count`). And so I will get `L1.Count` no of lists. So I need to create `var v={ }` dynamically. How to do this? If you have any other solution, it is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make `v` a dictionary. The serializer will generate identical JSON for you as you would have had with the dynamic object.

```
var v = new Dictionary<string, SeatPlans>();

int id = 0;
foreach (SeatPlans sp in allUser)
{
    v.Add($"allUser{id}", sp);
    id++;
}

return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: the above answer solve the problem thank u.now i have litle difernt requirement. in array v the first or the last item shoud be list of different class how to do that.i have to send the list L1(list of layout )also in v with allUser[]

Comment: Please ask a new question for that. Provide what you have got and where exactly you experience a problem.